# getOrgChart: How to customize the boxes?

Tags: jquery, getorgchart

I understand that we can customize the look and feel of the nodes by defining a new theme. But I am not able to figure out how to create very custom looking nodes like this - [Node Design:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTY78.png)

I have checked out the demo example for creating your own theme. The definition looks like this:

```
    getOrgChart.themes.myCustomTheme =
    {
        size: [170, 230],
        toolbarHeight: 46,
        textPoints: [
            { x: 10, y: 200, width: 170 }
        ],
        text: '<text width="[width]" class="get-text get-text-[index]" x="[x]" y="[y]">[text]</text>',
        image: '<clipPath id="getMonicaClip"><circle cx="85" cy="85" r="85" /></clipPath><image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#getMonicaClip)" xlink:href="[href]" x="0" y="0" height="170" width="170"/>'
    };
```

But tweaking this code to make it look like the design in the attached image seems very difficult. If I resize the node rectangles, the lines that connect don't get resized.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If  you resize the rectangle also you should change the size properties

Comment: Doing that makes the text come out of the box. Also the connecting lines and '+' symbol also gets misaligned. In short, changing the value of the `d` attribute in `<path class=\"get-box\" d=\"M0 0 L300 0 L300 120 L0 120 Z\"/>` messes up the whole chart.